# HighCharts: column grouped drill down

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do drilled down on column grouped chart.

Attaching here the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fbCE2/2/

When I drill down to the first level, I don't see proper data from the `Categories1` defined here.
In my code, I have all these second level categories and data are dynamic.

Data:

```
**Region  |  ProgramLevel          |  UniversityCount**
-------------------------------------------------
East      |  Gold                  |  1
North     |  Gold,Silver           |  1,2
Northeast |  Silver                |  1
West      |  Gold,Platinum,Silver  |  3,2,2
```

I want these program level data in the drill down to the region group.

Can anyone please correct my `jsfiddle` to be working as per this requirement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, each of points should have a drilldown, while nothing have it, see:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'University',
        data: [1, 3, 1, 7],
        color: colors[0]
    }, {
        name: 'Internship',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 2],
        color: colors[1]

    }, {
        name: 'Employment',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 9],
        color: colors[2]
    }],
```

should be (for each series!):

```
    data: [{
        y: 1, 
        drilldown: {
            name: 'East',
            categories: categories1,
            data: [0, 1, 0],
            pointWidth: 40,
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        y: 3, 
        drilldown: {
            name: 'North',
            categories: categories1,
            data: [2, 1, 0],
            pointWidth: 40,
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }, {
        y: 1
    ...  

    }]
```